# Unable to invoke python inside the script within azure-devops pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, azure, shell, azure-devops, yaml

i am trying to call pytest function inside the script within the azure-devops pipeline

below is the code

```
\parameters:
- name: jobName
  type: string

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  variables:
    my_id: "your_id_here"
    my_token: "your_token_here"
  steps:
  - task: PythonScript@0
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'inline'
      script: |
        import subprocess
        import os
        import sys

        def run_pytest(test_case):
            test_case_name = ''
            if test_case == 'Pytest2':
                test_case_name = 'not Pytest2'
            else:
                test_case_name = 'Pytest2'
            result = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'pytest', '-v', 'tests', '-k', test_case_name])
            return result.returncode

  - ${{ if or(eq(parameters.jobName, 'Pytest1'), eq(parameters.jobName, 'Pytest2')) }}:
    - script: |
        exit_code = run_pytest('${{ parameters.jobName }}')
        if exit_code != 0:
            print('Tests failed')
            sys.exit(1)
      displayName: 'Run Pytest'

  - ${{ if not(or(eq(parameters.jobName, 'Pytest1'), eq(parameters.jobName, 'Pytest2'))) }}:
    - script: |
        echo "Invalid jobName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}"
        exit 1
      displayName: 'Invalid Job Name'
```

But while running the pipeline, it throwing the error

"Syntax error near unexpected token 'run_pytest(Pytest2)'
Pytest2 is the parameters.jobName
Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code that i have rewritten .

```
parameters:
- name: jobName
  type: string
  default: myjob_s

jobs:
- job: ${{parameters.jobName}}
  variables:
    my_id: "your_id_here"
    my_token: "your_token_here"
  steps:
  - task: PythonScript@0
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'inline'
      script: |
        import subprocess
        import os
        import sys

        def run_pytest(test_case):
            test_case_name = os.path.basename(test_case)
            result = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'pytest', '-v', 'tests', '-k', test_case_name])
            return result.returncode

        if parameters.jobName == 'Pytest1' or parameters.jobName == 'Pytest2':
            exit_code = run_pytest(parameters.jobName)
            if exit_code != 0:
                print('Tests failed')
                sys.exit(1)
        else:
            echo "Invalid jobName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}"
            exit 1
      displayName: 'Run Pytest'
```

on run_pytest(parameters.jobName) variable interpolation is not needed. variables can be used directly . Gave job parameter a default value .